# Fails installing MySql on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, centos7

Why does it have something to do with mariadb? I had a fresh installation of CentOS 7 and wanted to install MySql community version. It seems to say I have to first install Mariadb server?

```
# yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: linux.mirrors.es.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.35-3.el7 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-server for package: akonadi-mysql-1.9.2-4.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.25-2.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.25-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) = 5.6.25-2.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.25-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.35-3.el7 will be obsoleted
---> Package mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.35-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb(x86-64) = 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.35-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 will be an update
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.35-3.el7 will be obsoleted
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.35-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 will be obsoleting
Removing mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 - u due to obsoletes from mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 - u
Removing mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 - u due to obsoletes from mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 - u
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 - u due to obsoletes from mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.25-2.el7 - u
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 will be an update
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 will be an update
---> Package mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-server for package: akonadi-mysql-1.9.2-4.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: akonadi-mysql-1.9.2-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: mariadb-server
           Removing: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               mariadb-server = 1:5.5.35-3.el7
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-server-5.6.25-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
               Not found
           Updated By: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 (base)
               mariadb-server = 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0
```

Comment: MariaDB is a compatible implementation of MySQL, and was already installed on your server. But installing the MySQL community distribution replaces it and the two cannot inhabit the same install as far as I know. It appears that akonadi has a mariadb dependency that MySQL community doesn't meet. Do you need akonadi? (part of the KDE desktop)

Comment: Does MariaDB as currently installed not meet your needs? Everything normally handled by MySQL will be done by mariadb, including the binaries `/usr/bin/mysql` and `/usr/sbin/mysqld`

Comment: I have an application in openshift, and database there is MySql. I am not sure whether I need akonadi, but I am using KDE desktop. Will it allow me to install MySql if I uninstall MariaDB?

Comment: Also, "command not found" when I executed "mariadb".

Comment: The executable it calls isn't `mariadb`, it is just `mysql` since it is a fully compatible replacement. Without changing your original MariaDB setup, run `mysql` on the command line (you may first need to start the server via `sudo systemctl start mysqld.service`). The client should start and the prompt will look something like `MariaDB [(none)]>`. Interact with it _exactly_ the same way you would with MySQL, and applications which use it will not see the difference.

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Mariadb doesn't sound like a very good name. Maybe "MyDB" is much simpler.

Comment: MySQL was named after the author's first daughter, MariaDB after his second. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-the-project-called-mariadb/

Answer (score 18):

In CentOS 7 - Maria DB is already installed. due to this you are facing the issue.{MariaDB is a compatible implementation of MySQL}.
If you want to install Mysql - first you should remove the current existing Mari DB.

Step 1 : Remove Maria DB completely 
         i.e.  yum -y remove mariadb-libs

Step 2 : Install MySQL

```
     i. wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
     ii. yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
     iii. yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
     iv. yum install mysql-community-server
     v. yum-config-manager --disable mysql57-community
     vi. yum-config-manager --enable mysql56-community
     viii. service mysqld start
     ix. service mysqld status
     x. mysql --version
     xi. mysql -u root -p
```

Regards,

Manjunath Naik

Comment: this killed my plesk installation. im dead x_x

Answer (score 8):

You should remove Maiadb first.

```
# yum -y remove mariadb-libs
```

Comment: elaborate your answer what is wrong with user code how it solves Op's problem not just one liner, edit your answer